# Combine multiple Bitcoin balances into a new wallet?

Tags: reward-schedule

I need $1000 worth of Bitcoin, but I'm going to use an ATM, and without I.D., there is a limit of $250 per transaction. Could I conduct 4 separate transactions back-to-back, tell the ATM to create a different wallet each time, and then later move those 4 balances into one wallet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use new address for each transaction and receive BTC in the same wallet.

Use one of the open source bitcoin wallets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

It is recommended to use a new receiving address for each transaction you receive.

Later, you can send all of the funds from that wallet, to a new address if you would like. But note that doing so will link your 4 transactions together, based on the [common input ownership heuristic](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy), so it is not great for your privacy.

If you need to send $1000 worth of BTC to someone, there realistically isn't much of a reason to first send the $1000 to yourself though. You can just send that transaction straight to them.

*Note: there are a number of scams which ask you to purchase BTC through an ATM, and then send it to the scammer. Beware of these scams, it is often best to just ignore them, and not pay the scammer.*